# How to retrieve records by as a range (As1-As10) in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

is there any possibility to retrieve records as a range.For an example there is a table with column as ref_numbers.Sample values for the ref_numbers  are A1,A2,A3,A4....AB1,AB2,AB3,AB4...
I want to retrieve the records of specific range starting value and end value.Such as in this case (A1-A2,AB1-AB4)
How can i achieve this ,Using eloquent or query builder or Raw queries in laravel?

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this where between operator.

```
$data = DB::table('table_name')
           ->whereBetween('ref_numbers', ['A1', 'A10'])
           ->get();
```

or

```
$data = DB::table('table_name')
           ->where('ref_numbers', '>', 'A1')
           ->where('ref_numbers', '<', 'A10')
           ->get();
```

You can read here more https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses